# Separar coluna em várias linhas (split)

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, select

Tenho uma tabela `cidade_bairro` com diversas cidades e bairros. Quero transferir esses dados para uma nova tabela, mas em diversas linhas ao invés de estarem em uma só.

EX:

```
Cidade  Bairros<br>
SP |    Consolação-Morumbi-Saude
```

Na nova tabela "cidade_bairro2" estariam separados em 3 linhas:

```
Cidade  Bairro
SP |    Consolação
SP | Morumbi
SP | Saude
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a realizar essa transferência via SQL MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma tabela de apoio com o número **máximo** de separações que os bairros podem ter. Mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE numeros (
  numero int
);

INSERT INTO numeros(numero)
VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5),
      (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);
```

E utilizar a seguinte `query` para extrair os dados:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cb.cidade,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cb.bairros, '-', n.numero), '-', -1) AS bairro
  FROM cidade_bairro cb
       CROSS JOIN numeros n
 ORDER BY cb.cidade, n.numero;
```

Note que o `DISTINCT` irá filtrar os resultados iguais.

Você pode conferir o resultado no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90aa40/2).

---

Você pode conseguir o número máximo de ocorrências de `-` na sua tabela com a `query` a seguir:

```
SELECT MAX(ROUND((LENGTH(cb.bairros) - LENGTH(REPLACE(cb.bairros, '-', ''))) / LENGTH('-'))) + 1 AS quantidade
  FROM cidade_bairro cb
```

---

**Referências:**

- [**Split string no MySQL**](https://gustavostraube.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/split-string-no-mysql/)
- [**SQL split values to multiple rows**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/3388148)
- [**Count the number of occurrences of a string in a VARCHAR field?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12344881/3388148)

Comment: Essa tabela possui milhares de linhas,o que torna difícil definir o valor "n" para cada uma das linhas

Comment: @Christian insira o tamanho máximo na tabela `numeros`. Não precisa ser o valor exato. Se você acha que o máximo vai ser 500 bairros em uma cidade, coloque 500 números lá. Passar um pouco não vai fazer mal, só prejudica um pouco a performance.