# Verificar se valor está em uma coluna

Tags: php, sql

Preciso verificar se um valor está em uma coluna no BD.
Minha coluna está com o conteúdo separado por vírgulas, assim: 1,2,3,4,5.
Logo, gostaria de saber como faço para verificar se o valor 2, por exemplo, está em alguma linha na coluna em SQL.

> Selecionar tudo de minha_tabela quando 1 estiver em minha_coluna

Estrutura da tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]:

Comment: "Preciso verificar se um valor está em uma coluna no BD". Você pode editar a pergunta e mostrar um exemplo das colunas com linhas? ;)

Comment: Pronto. Veja se esta mais visivel.

Comment: Você quer saber o jeito php de fazer essa operação ou no banco mesmo?

Comment: Sem nenhuma amostra do que tentou? Ai a sua pergunta pode ser fechada como não está muito clara, nem sabemos se o que quer (onde está o problema) é em `sql`, `php`, ou um mix dos dois...

Comment: Sugiro fortemente a leitura: Como criar um [MCVE]

Comment: Pronto, tente entender agora.

Comment: É, e se a coluna for: 102,201,304,852,214. A linha vai ser selecionada sendo que não existe o 2 somente nela.

Comment: E se o 2 estiver no final da string: 104,201,450,201,2 ?

Comment: Por que apagou as respostas? kkj.

Comment: Porque se não resolviam a sua pergunta, só geravam o que chamamos de poluição visual =], melhor apagar. Como irei fazer com esse comentário daqui a pouco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na realidade a sua tabela foi projetada incorretamente. O correto seria ter uma tabela de apoio com os códigos e um vínculo para essa tabela. Porém caso não exista possibilidade de alterar a tabela você pode utilizar as seguintes opções:

---

**1) DISTINCT + SUBSTRING_INDEX + Tabela de Apoio**

Aplicando a teoria [**dessa resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237082/59479) temos a seguinte `query` para a busca proposta:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.id,
                        t.id_busca,
                        t.players,
                        TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.players, ',', n.numero), ',', -1)) AS ocorrencia
          FROM tabela t
               CROSS JOIN numeros n
         ORDER BY t.id, n.numero) x
 WHERE x.ocorrencia = 2
```

Você pode conferir a execução no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c1b1f/3).

Na solução acima criamos uma tabela de apoio (denominada `numeros`) com as posições possíveis. Note que os números **não são os valores** e sim as **posições** e com o `CROSS JOIN` com essa tabela realizamos o `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, permitindo assim que todas as posições (separadas por vírgula) sejam cobertas. Note se que se utilizei apenas 10 números no exemplo, porém se houverem mais posições possíveis a tabela de apoio deve ser preenchida de acordo com as possibilidades (sempre para mais).

---

**1) FIND_IN_SET**

Uma outra solução é utilizar a função [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.id_busca,
       t.players
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, t.players)
```

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86896d/1).

---

**Referências:**

- [**Split string no MySQL**](https://gustavostraube.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/split-string-no-mysql/)
- [**SQL split values to multiple rows**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/3388148)
- [**Count the number of occurrences of a string in a VARCHAR field?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12344881/3388148)

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pela resposta. E será que você pode me dizer, qual o problema de guardar informações em uma coluna desta maneira? Pois eu tenho uma outra tabela com o mesmo tipo de estrutura, e funcionou perfeitamente. Será que o problema seria na hora de tratar esse dados?

Comment: @VitorLeite dificulta a busca e não há necessidade de fazer um tratamento tão pesado para buscar e inserir nessa tabela. Como foi citado na outra pergunta que você fez, há outras formas mais fáceis e normalizadas de resolver esse problema