# Seria possível listar o enum de um campo de uma tabela através de uma query?

Tags: mysql, enums

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de trazer os valores do inseridos no `ENUM` de uma coluna de uma tabela através de uma query.

Por exemplo, com essa tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
    name VARCHAR(40),
    size ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large')
);
```

Teria como listar os valores `x-small`, `small`, `medium`, `large` e `x-large` através de um `SELECT`?

**Observação**: Não quero pegar os valores dos dados inseridos na tabela, e sim a lista que está dentro da declaração do `ENUM`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A própria [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) cita isso:

> *To determine all possible values for an ENUM column, use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_name LIKE 'enum_col'` and parse the ENUM definition in the Type column of the output.*

Que em tradução livre: para determinar todos os possíveis valores de uma coluna ENUM utilize `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_name LIKE 'enum_col'` e trate a definição do ENUM na coluna Type do resultado.

Para o seu exemplo:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM shirts LIKE 'size';
```

Obtendo o resultado:

```
| Field | Type                                               | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| ----- | -------------------------------------------------- | ---- | --- | ------- | ----- |
| size  | enum('x-small','small','medium','large','x-large') | YES  |     |         |       |
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no  [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k6nFw7xE561GeSBTQj3WPB/0)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar as informações da tabela `information_schema.columns` separando as informações como sugerido na resposta da pergunta [**Separar coluna em várias linhas (split)**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237082/59479).

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
  name VARCHAR(40),
  size ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large')
);

CREATE TABLE numeros (
  numero int
);

INSERT INTO numeros(numero)
VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5),
      (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(c.column_type, 'enum(', ''), ')', ''), '''', ''), ',', n.numero), ',', -1) AS valor
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 CROSS JOIN numeros n
  WHERE c.table_name = 'shirts'
    AND c.column_name = 'size';
```

---

**Resultando em**

```
| valor   |
| ------- |
| x-small |
| small   |
| medium  |
| large   |
| x-large |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uexivRQTjgp5BJhSRg8Mey/0).

---

> [**INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html)
>
> The [`COLUMNS`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237082/59479) table provides information about columns in tables.

Em tradução livre:

> A tabela [`COLUMNS`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237082/59479) provê informações sobre as colunas das tabelas.

Answer (score -2):

Uso este script com PHP (é só adaptar para a linguagem em que você está programando):

```
$table_name = "nome_da_sua_tabela";
$column_name = "nome_da_sua_coluna";
echo "<select name=\"$column_name\">";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$column_name'")
or die (mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$enumList = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", substr($row['COLUMN_TYPE'], 5, (strlen($row['COLUMN_TYPE'])-6))));

foreach($enumList as $value)
    echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
echo "</select>";
```